# Как загрузить страницу, но не показывать ее?

Tags: android

Привет всем!   
Интересно, а можно ли как-то, подгрузив страницу в фоне, не показывать ее пользователю?

С подгрузкой в фоне все понятно, а вот чтобы не показывать у меня вопрос.   
Допустим, приложение — это просто какая-то игрушка. Хотелось бы, пока пользователь играет (или наоборот - пока приложение не активно), где-то в фоне подгружалась страницы и не показывалась пользователю вообще никак. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Типа, накрутки рекламы что ли делать?..

Comment: мне кажется, ни один рекламодатель не захочет с подобным иметь дело - какой смысл от показа скрытого от пользователя? Да и потом, это как-то может помочь делу?

Comment: На пример, можно получить HTML-код страницы в сервисе, или через AsyncTask, и после - загрузить его в webView...

Comment: да, но это же по сути будет примерно то же, что и просмотр страницы через браузер, т.е. откроется окно, что не хотелось бы...

Comment: Можно просто вызвать [setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)][1] контейнера этого View, в котором страница загрузилась. 


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29